# Shift time chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

[JSFiddle](http://vk.cc/3HmGAT)

How can I make as drawing, chart smoothly moved back as [**here**](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update)?

The problem is that I have added:

```
min: date.getTime() - 130000,
max: date.getTime() + 130000
```

that there is free space on the right and then he stopped to shift.

Maybe there is a simpler solution to the right place and had not had to suffer with the shift?

Comment: What do you exactly expect to happen? If you remove min and max what will be missing?

Comment: @Raeen Hashemi if I remove the min and max, it will disappear and so http://jsfiddle.net/ze2gabks/3/ line. I need to look like this http://c2n.me/3gnfoY0.png

Comment: So what do you want the chart to do after moving over the red line?

Comment: You can use a maxPadding, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/ze2gabks/4/

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan Crooked works. When the schedule begins to dynamically draw, it becomes a little and get all terribly

Comment: @ruslan - can you explain what the problem is with the maxPadding solution? '2' is too high probably, but at 0.25, it looks quite nice to me.

Comment: @jlbriggs maxPadding can do without? He makes a chart ugly and mouse not working shift